# How can we capture run time values using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium2

How can we capture run time values using selenium webdriver ?

For e.g while testing a banking site, we provide all details necessary to create a new customer and click submit. A customer ID is generated shown in the next page with the details of the customer listed in a tabular format (after successful new customer creation). How do we capture this ID ?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you just want to find the value on the page, so you can use it as a variable in your test method?

Answer (score 1):

If ID is shown on the page - it is shown as text in some element. Which has some locator. Find that element and get it's text or value property, as appropriate.